# 0xDEADBEEF is not tasty, but still 0xFEEDBEEF

Tags: code-golf, string, hexadecimal

*Inspired by ["You had me at hello"](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/115207/you-had-me-at-hello)*

## Introduction

For those who don't know, hexadecimal is a base system like decimal. Contrary to decimal however, it uses 16 (hence the name) digits instead of 10.

Here are the first few numbers while counting up in hexadecimal to maybe give you a feel of things, although you should probably google it for more info.

`0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, A, B, C, D, E, F, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 1A, 1B, 1C, 1D, 1E, 1F, 20...`

From now on I'll refer to hexadecimal as hex.

---

## Challenge

Take a possibly infinite stream of bytes, and convert it to hex. This should be done as you read since you might get an infinite stream and keep on reading forever.

The twist, is that if a sequence of converted numbers equals the exact hex number `DEADBEEF` (3735928559 in decimal), you must output `FEEDBEEF` (4276993775 in decimal) instead.

If no `DEADBEEF` is found, print the string as it was

Inter-character matches work too, so `2D EA DB EE F0` works and should be converted to `2F EE DB EE F`

---

## Example

This might seem a bit vague, so here are 2 step-by-step examples.

#### Example 1

Input: `Hello, World` (bytes represented as string)

> Step 1: Convert the input to ASCII: `072 101 108 108 111 044 032 087 111 114 108 100`
>
> Step 2: Convert the ASCII to hex: `48 65 6C 6C 6F 2C 20 57 6F 72 6C 64`
>
> Step 3: Print out everything until `DEADBEEF` is found. It wasn't found, so just print `Hello, World` again.

#### Example 2

Input: `Hello,Þ­¾ï,,`

> Step 1: Convert to ASCII: `72 101 108 108 111 44 222 173 190 239 44 44`
>
> Step 2: Convert to hex: `48 65 6C 6C 6F 2C DE AD BE EF 2C 2C`
>
> Step 3: Is there `DEADBEEF`? Yep. so take everything up to it. `48 65 6C 6C 6F 2C`
>
> Step 4: Append `FEEDBEEF` to it. `48 65 6C 6C 6F 2C FE ED BE EF`
>
> Step 5: Convert back to a string and print it. Output is `Hello,þí¾ï`

---

## Scoring

Try to make a program that does the above in the **fewest bytes of source code as possible**.

---

## Remember!

Make sure your program works for finite and infinite streams. The stream can be STDIN, file, function argument (if you can pass streams as arguments), or your language's closest alternative. Output is to STDOUT or function returning (if you can return streams).

## More test cases (contain invisible characters)

`eeþí¾Þ­¾ïe (6565feedbedeadbeef65) -> eeþí¾þí¾ïe`
`Þ­¾ï (deadbeef)-> þí¾ï`
`Þ=êÛîôV -> Þ?îÛîôV`

Comment: "Take a ... stream of printable ASCII characters". `Þ` from your 2nd example isn't a printable ascii character.

Comment: @Rogem Printable ascii is a [defined range of code points](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Printable_characters)

Comment: If an inter-match is found, like input `-êÛîð` (`2D EA DB EE F0`), do we convert it to `2F EE DB EE F0` (resulting in string `-êÛîð`) or `2F EE DB EE F` (resulting in string `-êÛî ` where the last character is the unprintable `\x0f`)?

Comment: Your test cases should be either pasted as TIO links or as hex dumps if they contain unprintable characters.

Comment: @mbomb007 There are hexdumps of the inputs, the outputs don't contain unprintable characters

Comment: I would format those extra test cases to make that clearer. I think it'd be better to format your test cases as [hex dump] => [hex dump].

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 121 bytes

```python
I=open(0).read
p=print
x=i=I(1)
while i:p(end=x[:-4]);x=x[-4:];x!='Þ­¾ï'or+p(end='þí¾ï');i=I(1);x+=i
p(end=x[:5])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/39M2vyA1T8NAU68oNTGFq8C2oCgzr4SrwjbT1lPDUJOrPCMzJ1Uh06pAIzUvxbYi2krXJFbTugLI0jWxirWuULRVPzzv0NpD@w6vV88v0oYoUz@87zBESNMaYo51hbZtJhfcENNYzf//PVJzcvJ1YLp1dAA)

Comment: `or+p(end=...)` causes a `TypeError: bad operand type for unary +: 'NoneType'`

Comment: A fixed version is here: https://tio.run/##RYwxCoNAEEX7PYXYuEvGoMRK2V5PYKEWuo4oLCqOoLlMbhBygxR6sI1ikerDe48/Pud26B/GJHIYsece2FNli/uEZc3Si/lgLydbpm5GRlLJhPuCLW2n0VJhyikL3aAQEUnK3CAsoquICJTklZOvDeYr1vlands44ImusUjK09UHK/8ONSGnmwIl2PEsjIlR6wH21/bevvsH4Ac

Comment: @mypetlion The error is on purpose, it crashes the program so that it stops outputting.

Comment: Oh yes that does make sense. I might have misread the spec.

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>34</s> 30 bytes

*-4 bytes from @Shagy*

```
csG r`Ü%¼ef.+``fe‚¼ef` ò ®nG d
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn/P7nYXaEo4fAc1UN7UtP0tBMS0lIPNYHYCQqHNykcWpfnrpDy/7@SR2pOTr6OwuF5h9Ye2nd4vY6OkoJuAAA)

Comment: Added more test cases

Comment: [30 bytes](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=Y3NHIHJg3CW8ZWYuK2BgZmWCvGVmYCDyIK5uRyBk&input=IkhlbGxvLN6tvu8sLCIKLVA=) using `S.c()` instead of `S.m()` and `S.r()` instead of `S.s()`.

Comment: @Shaggy Damn, I dont know how I didnt see those methods :o

Answer (score 1):

## [Clean](https://github.com/Ourous/curated-clean-linux), 143 bytes

*uses octal escapes here and on TIO to prevent UTF-8 mangling, but it does work with the actual values and so each escape sequence is counted as one byte*

This one works with inter-character sequences.

```
import StdEnv
$l=:[a,'\352\333\356',b:t]|(toInt a)rem 16==13&&(toInt b)>>4==15=[a+'\002':['\356\333\356\015']]=[hd l: $(tl l)]
$['\336\255\276\357':_]=['\376\355\276\357']
$[h:t]=[h: $t]
$e=e
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bU5Na4NAED3HXzEHyUbyrdUUYXNqSwOFHpKedAmjjlVY3ZDdJBT622vX0A8KPc3Me2/ee7kkbLtGFSdJ0GDddnVzUEcDW1Pct2fHlTxOcMLSIPTTIAjsjNgki414Hxm1aQ2gd6QGlhHny2A4/AIzb72@sUjIExyzdLHwWZz0JtG3SbpYhkwInlQFyBjckZEgPeG4vSyIUj8MU39l5eGKxXurs/D1/IV7cWWbWA9rYOxJnLqtQVufgwujhD2SlGrCBIzHUBAWGVHZ7wnTqiFQpqIjaHMqSxbXbVm3taF9XuFRC8@5WJKcwc8fh3@6CZjPIaMcT5pgt3kGOzW87B6mt6AVXAgqPBMY1ROgcoMSSOd4IO0M/kZeA5DNZqL7yEuJr7qbbp66u7cWmzrXnw)

## [Clean](https://github.com/Ourous/curated-clean-linux), 38 bytes

*uses octal escapes here and on TIO to prevent UTF-8 mangling, but it does work with the actual values and so each escape sequence is counted as one byte*

This one does not work with inter-character sequences.

```
$['\336\352\276\357':_]=['\376\355\276\357']
$[h:t]=[h: $t]
$e=e
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bU/LasMwEDzHX7EHg1rygpg0xeBbWxoo9JD05JiwkVe1iiwFa500P19XyiFQ6GlnZ9idGWkI7dC6ujcELWo7pKXYZdnDLlsudotVnCuR76si0td1eaOrJC2bnIPW5JByWKmgQbdH1zFsuH62J5jP4UxQOysYUHKPxlyg9wTcaA/KdQEQqN5K1s5O4Kv3fKPpG9ujoWTDGD4WkMJdKV7JGDcRFYzHUBPWByIVcSm8awlcOOzAc6@UyLVV2mqmvWyw89V9cg4iJaPbXQH/1K1i6gNJjDm36/eY18PH9mX6CN7FPg2eQgN3LeIkowHyEo/kk9Ffy6sBitmsGn6kMvjph@n6bXi6WGy19L8)

Defines the function `$ :: [Char] -> [Char]` taking and returning a list of characters.
 Since Clean is lazily-evaluated, this is equivalent to a stream.

Comment: Does it work with things like hex(`0DEADBEEF9`)

Comment: @FireCubez no, as that wasn't clearly required at the one I wrote this. I'll update it today so that it does.

Comment: @FireCubez with interchacter matches, what is the second digit of the last `F`? Do we use `0x0F`? `0xF0`?

Comment: @Ourous `0x0F` would be used

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 30 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
ÇhJl’–ìÀÜ’¡Dнsg1›’ŽåÀÜ’×«2ôHçJ
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//cHuGV86jhpmPGiYfXnO44fAcIPvQQpcLe4vTDR817ALyju49vBQqcXj6odVGh7d4HF7u9f@/R2pOTr6C7uFVh2cfXnd4g0J5flFOiiIA) or [verify a few more test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfeX/w@0ZXjmPGmY@aph8eM3hhsNzgOxDC10u7C1ON3zUsAvIO7r38FKoxOHph1YbHd7icXi513@d/9FKHqk5OfkKuodXHZ59eN3hDQrl@UU5KYpKOgpKHpkQCqRA5/C8Q2sP7Tu8XkcHLJZfjqQlMSm/tEQBpkKhpDzfXikWAA).

**Explanation:**

```python
Ç                               # Convert the (implicit) input-string to codepoint decimals
 h                              # Convert them to hexadecimal
  J                             # Join them together
   l                            # Convert to lowercase
    ’–ìÀÜ’                      # Push compressed string "deadbeef"
          ¡                     # Split the hexadecimal string by this "deadbeef"
           D                    # Duplicate
            н                   # Take the first item of the split-list
             s                  # Swap so the full list is at the top of the stack again
              g1›               # Check if its length is larger than 1
                 ’ŽåÀÜ’×«       # If it is: concat "feedbeef" to the head-string
                         2ô     # Split the string into parts of size 2
                           H    # Convert hexadecimal back to decimal
                            ç   # Decimal back to characters
                             J  # Join the characters (and output implicitly)
```

[See this 05AB1E tips of mine (section *How to use the dictionary?*)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166851/52210) to understand why `’–ìÀÜ’` is `"deadbeef"` and `’ŽåÀÜ’` is `"feedbeef"`.

Comment: Why does it stop output when reaching a DEADBEEF?

Comment: @l4m2 Because that is the challenge.. :) (I.e. in the second example, the two trailing `,,` aren't output. It stops as soon as it found the `DEADBEEF` and appended the `FEEDBEEF` instead.)

Comment: See. The question is inconsistant

Comment: @l4m2 I agree. Although the other answers thus far (Python, Japt, and Clean) interpret it in the same way as me.

Answer (score 0):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 137 bytes

```c
i=16;n;long long u;c;R(k){u=u<<4|c>>k&15,u^=u+'!RA'<<32?0:' @';}main(){for(;n+=!!~(c=getchar(n-=!i&&~putchar(u>>32)));i/=2)R(4),R(0);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XU/bTsJAFOSZN/9girHdDRDb3ZYYt1sFWj6gTz5pyFJqgy6ksEkThF8vFLFGk8lJzmVmzqhhrlRd6B3e8myn3uclodijGVRy6Als1VwvSe@u6g1gV1SgzHam1KgEDt0Lb2O@eUZvi1xnCzQdqkZmU54vGrbLXnAW@M/v3i6yZaEzXL3bJ9rFVbx1qQvpjYQWH2ud41KMUCIlK7o30oSh/6WiaGV7wcC8StN3rHR844QhZ0/uo4PnTscRh895oQndL9clEbovLetIlPxJr4fSKmz72KaKIs4opaK4l4ymxKeDlLhUHOqae@AMnIP74AHcGMkY8QRJgpkHxuEHiBOMY0wSJDO47i/8B4wCjKYXzMCmfy7PLZueAA)

Comment: @ceilingcat `c` is used in `R`, so can't move